# When I choose the shading mode, the under working view of the selection was hidden

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, shaders, selection-tools, object-mode

[image]

I don't know what I did with the mouse, the under working view was hidden all of the selection, and I can't find it.

How can I open the view of the under working view?

Comment: Hi, the shader editor has infinite space in any direction, I guess that you have somehow went too far away in one direction... Instead of trying to find it manually try to Press A and then press , on your numpad, this will focus your view on your nodes

Comment: Thank you for your teaching and guidance!!!❤️❤️❤️

Comment: I find the another answer : Ctrl + F in the Node Editor brings up a search menu.